# Bat to Prefix File names with folder characters & suffix with date

Tags: batch-file, cmd, renaming

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to bat/cmd stuff.
I can do the very very basics with a little help from google! & when i mean basic im talking xcopy, robocopy etc.

I am trying to write a code that will extract the 1st 5 characters from the current folder & rename files within a subfolder but also suffix with the current date.

So this is basically what im trying to do.

`W:\12345_folder`  This is the main folder that I want to extract the 12345 from.

`W:\12345_folder\subfolder`  This is the location for the files that are to be renamed

Current name of files within subfolder are as follows

`file1.txt`
`file2.txt`
`file3.txt`

After renaming they should be as below

`12345 file1 2014-10-02.txt`
`12345 file2 2014-10-02.txt`
`12345 file3 2014-10-02.txt`

All my efforts have been in vain. I can get the date using this. But it renames the whole filename & does not retain the existing filename.

`for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do rename "*.txt" %%g%%f-%%e-%%d.txt`

And I have also been playing with this:

`for %%z in ("%cd%") do (
   for %%a in ("%%~dpz%\.") do (
      rename "**.txt" "%%~nxa-.txt"))`

But again this overwrites the whole filename and does not retain the existing file name.

I must stress once again I am a complete novice so be gentle & your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've managed to Suffix my file names with the date using the following code. `@ECHO OFF
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") DO (SET TODAY=%%f-%%e-%%d)

for %%a in (*.txt) do ren "%%~a" "%%~na %TODAY%%%~xa"` Now i just need some help with the prefix folder names

Comment: Right got the folder name renaming working `for %%z in ("%cd%") do (
for %%a in ("%%~dpz%\.") do (
for %%i in (*.pdf,*.xlsx,*.docx,*.xlsm) do move "%%i" "%%~nxz_ %%i"))` What would be very useful would be it this code only took the 1st 5 characters from the folder name. This is only thing left for me to work out now so any help would be great. Im sure its very simple for someone im having no luck. I'm not even quite sure how i managed to get the above code to work!

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with the RENAME command in Windows has some bugs, specifically with assigning prefixes and suffixes (see bottom link).

I only did part of the answer because I wasn't able to get date working as a suffix. But, this will allow you to prefix filenames in a directory with the prefix of your choosing, including the date.

I tried to get a "date as a suffix" solution working, but I had no success with the following on my version of cmd:

```
    REN *.txt ????????????????abc.txt.x
    REN *.x *
```

Returns: Invalid name

Here is my alternate solution, to add a prefix date.  For your first batch example, create two batch files:

renprefix.bat

```
    %4
    FOR %%v IN (%1) DO CALL %0 %1 %2 %%v GOTO:Part2
    ATTRIB -h %2%1
    GOTO End
    :Part2
    REN %3 %2%3
    ATTRIB +h %2%3
    :End
```

Then, use the above batch file in your example:

rendate.bat

```
    for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do renprefix.bat *.txt %%g%%f-%%e-%%d
```

Source:
http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/DOS7/z-ren1.html
"4. Adding a prefix"

Comment: I thanks for the reply. I couldnt get this work. I also tried a few of the examples from the link but still not working. It doesnt seem to rename anything. Very confused now.