# Renaming BAT suddenly not working correctly

Tags: batch-file, cmd, file-rename, batch-rename

Bit of a strange thing is happening to me.
I put a renaming batch file together a few years ago (with a lot of help from various places, including [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165578/bat-to-prefix-file-names-with-folder-characters-suffix-with-date)) for a project i was working on.
It would rename some files and prefix them with the first 5 characters from the parent folder (i.e. '12345 - Site').
I haven't used the BAT file for a good few months and now have a need to, but it is not working correctly.

It is renaming the files, but it is using the whole of the parent folder instead of just the first 5 characters. I have tested it on another PC and run it in folders where it previously worked.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this would happen, how to fix it, or what I could add to the batch file to achieve the same result?

Just to point out, I am a complete novice and spent many nights getting the first batch file working through trial and error and cutting and pasting from similar batch file requests on the web.

My current code:

```
for %%z in ("%cd%") do (
for %%a in ("%%~dpz%\.") do (
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir  /b /a-d *.pdf,*.xlsx,*.docx,*.xlsm') do move "%%i" "%%~nxz %%i"))
```

Comment: there is nothing in the code that could shorten anything to "first 5 characters". If it previously did, it was another batchfile.

Comment: Its looking like my original has been over written then. :(  Is there a way to extract the 1st 5 characters from this?

Comment: the intention of your batch is not clear to me, the first FOR loop should just run once, for the value of the current directory, and the index %a of the second FOR is not used at all, it just repeats using the first %z index. What is the value you want to extract the first 5 chars from?

Comment: please post your original BAT code

Comment: This is my BAT code, as i wrote in the post I am a complete novice & the code was made using the web & adapting existing codes. I have no understanding as to what the values do apart from the very very basic *.pdf etc. What i need the code to do is prefix the file names with the 1st 5 character of the folder they are in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
for %%z in ("%cd%") do (
    for %%a in ("%%~dpz%\.") do (
        for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir  /b /a-d *.pdf,*.xlsx,*.docx,*.xlsm') do call :renameStuff "%%i" "%%~nxz"
        )
    )
goto :eof

:renameStuff
set "originalName=%~1"
set "parentFolder=%~2"
echo move "%originalName%" "%parentFolder:~0,5% %originalName%"
exit /b
```

The specific bit you're looking for is `%parentFolder:~0,5%`, which takes a substring of %parentFolder% starting at character 0 and stopping after 5 characters.  This gives you the first 5 characters that you're looking for.

The tricky bit is that you can't use this on those `for` loop `%%z` type variables.  Thus, you have to pass it to another variable.  Further, because you've got some nested loops delayed expansion makes this really ugly, so I've passed the variable into a subroutine (`call :renameStuff "%%i" "%%~nxz"`) which turns those into `%1` and `%2` type variables, and then passed it into ordinary variables (`set "originalName=%~1"`) that this will work with.

Comment: @legg1979: the `echo` just prints the `move` command to screen instead of executing it (security reasons). Once the output looks fine, just remove the word `echo`. You may also want to insert `@echo off` as the very first line. It tells the script, to not print every command to the screen before executing. (these are the very basics, but as you claim to be a complete noob, I thought it's worth mentioning)

Comment: The `for %%a` loop (already present in the original code) is completely senseless, `%%a` is never used; (if it made sense, its set `%%~dpz%\.` should read `%%~dpz.`); it enumerates all items of the parent directory of the current directory, but the iterated items are never used; in every iteration, the inner `for /F` loop tries to rename the files, so it may happen that the files are preceded with multiple five-character prefixes finally...

Comment: @Wes Larson Thanks, your code sort of reminds me of an extra part that may have been in the original. Im sure it somehow got overwritten. I have double backed it up now tho!!

Comment: @Stephan Thanks for your little bit of knowledge every little helps :) & sorry for being such a noob!